# How to use Pentadactyl style/styleenable?

Tags: pentadactyl

I tried `:style -name=codesnippet craftyjs.com pre code {background-color: transparent;}`
but nothing happened, apparently. Then I tried `:styleenable -name=codesnippet` but nothing happend, either. How am I supposed to use this commands?

I'm running Pentadactyl nightly and Firefox 18 (stable).

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is CSS Specificity ([See Chris Coyier's post](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) for a nice description). You can add an `!important` to make this work.

```
:style -name=cs craftyjs.com pre code {background-color: transparent !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since your original question, so perhaps the craftyjs site has changed since then. In any case, I couldn't find a specific element that matched your example CSS selector. So, I'll just provide an example with the site I see today.

Let's use this page as an example: [Crafty.settings](http://craftyjs.com/api/Crafty-settings.html). Look at those lovely parameter lists! So grey. I hate grey. In fact, I hate parameter lists. Let's pretend they don't exist:

```
:style -name=ewww craftyjs.com dl {display:none;}
```

Gone. Ahh.

Now, you may very well ask, why does this work, when your finely crafted example did not? I don't know!

Here's a slightly modified example:

```
:style -name=ewww craftyjs.com dl {background:#f00;}
```

Doesn't work! This does, though:

```
:style -name=ewww craftyjs.com dl {color:#f00;}
```

Hmmm. We notice that pentadactyl doesn't offer "background" as a completion.  Maybe:

```
:style -name=ewww craftyjs.com dl {background-color:#f00;}
```

No. Well, perhaps the Firefox developer tools can help us. Inspecting the parameter list box (while sneering silently to ourselves) shows this as the full setting: `none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238)`. Let's change it to blue: `background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(0, 0, 238)`. Very nice! A comforting retro look. Reset it to gray, so that we can do it with Pentadactyl, like this:

```
:style -name=ewww craftyjs.com dl {background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(0, 0, 255)}
```

Argh. Sorrow. Back to normal. Looks like we found a bug! I like this bug so
much, I gave it a special name: Pentadactly issue #[969](http://code.google.com/p/dactyl/issues/detail?id=989). Catchy, right?

**Update**: Aaaand, Peter Wooley FTW! (And now I know more about CSS. Possibly more than I wanted.) Recommended closing the new Pentdactyl issue.